# Why would Moksha be permanent?

Tags: brahman, moksha

If individuals came from Brahman which is unchanging and perfect... then if we attain Moksha (merge into Brahman), what's to stop Brahman from creating us again? If we were created once, and Brahman is unchanging, the same problem could happen again couldn't it? Seems like a never-ending cycle.

Comment: Even if it is not permanent it is still much worth doing. The people who come down from the higher realms like Jaya and Vijaya lead much more dramatic, interesting, powerful lives than normal. So a permanent benefit is there even if moksha itself is not.

Comment: ...by creating 'who' again? Your jiva, your material body, Who? Your fine body? Who?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, let's say all of that is recreated.